# Get List Column configuration using pnp.js

Tags: list, column, pnpjs

I want to fetch the List column configuation to check if a field is required or not.

But I am not able to figure out which function to use by looking at the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your endpoint like given REST endpoint below:

```
siteUrl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/fields?$select=Title,Required
```

Something like:

```
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";
let web = sp.web;
// get the fields in a list
web.lists.getByTitle("MyList").fields.get().then(f => {
    console.log("Field: " + f.Title);
    console.log("Required: " + f.Required);
});
```

**Reference**:

[PnP JS - Fields](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/docs/fields/).

Comment: Yeah I already used this Function, but the Required values do not match what is specified in the list settings (only the title is required). And a field that is created in the list settings is not even showing up in the response.

Comment: Is it not showing the custom fields you created in list?

Comment: Also, you can get the specific fields you want from list by using their internal names. For this, check **Filtering Fields - Application specific fields** section in reference link code.

Comment: Ohh it turns out that I have been executing my querys on a different list than I thought. (thats why the the fields I'm creating aren't showing up and nothing is working as expected)